# How to use if controller in JMeter to check the file name

Tags: if-statement, groovy, jmeter, performance-testing

I have 125 thread group in my JMeter test plan. Now i have to run my test in master slave method with 5 slaves. But i have to run only first 25 thread group in 1 slave.
Example:
Slave-1 - Thread group 1 to 25
Slave-2 - Thread group 26 to 50 --- Slave-5 - Thread group 100 to 125

Now i will place my CSV data file accordingly.Means file 1 to 25 in slave and so on.But when i click run option all the 125 threads will start in all slave.

So i have to validate the file name using If controller and if it exist it should run in that slave or else it should run.

Kindly provide your logic by using the if controller in jmeter. Any suggestion will be great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following in your [IF Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) to check if the file exists

```
${__groovy(((new File("/Users/hansi/Documents/training/jmeter/install/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/jmeter.sh")).exists()))}
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Thank you so much. it worked. i have also tried with the  variable name inside that file which will be unique fro all my script as below.
${__javaScript("${CenterNum}" == "370",)}

But now i have another problem. I am getting warning error message if the file is not available in that place. But instead of that if it is not available it should not run in that particular slave and continue on other slave with out throwing any error.

Any suggestion will be a great help